# Anosov flows on non-compact manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

So, when defining Anosov flows on a compact manifold specifying the Riemannian metric is not necessary as any two are equivalent. So, my question is:

Given a non compact manifold $M$ and a proper flow $\Phi_{t}:M \rightarrow M$, can we always put an "ad-hoc" metric such that the flow is Anosov?

Some further thoughts of mine: 
The first example of Anosov flow that comes to my mind are that of the geodesic flow on $\mathbb{H}^{2}$. Inspired by this:

Given a metrizable topological space $X$, and a simple path( not finite or infinite in particular ) $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow X$, can we always put another metric on $X$ such that the path is geodesic?

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but what is a proper flow? I believe Anosov flows have important topological properties, a silly one is that it cannot be periodic.

Comment: Yes you're right and the periodicity assumption can be put in place as well. By proper I meant that the flow seen as an action on $M$ is a proper action in the usual sense. Sorry for the late reply.